# Ajax/jquery/php: one product with different color with different pictures

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making custom shop-cms. And at this point I am stuck, trying to make for each product possibility for picking colors and for each color 1-5 picture(s). And I just can't understand the most reasonable solution, how should the form look like. The point is that I clone the CREATE form on page load for less code purposes, making an EDIT form out of it. When I click on product's EDIT button it makes a request to DB picking all the information according to the chosen ID. The way I see it is that I have to have main hidden input where I keep all the information about all the colors and related pictures on other inputs change. That will do with creating new product. But when it comes to editing, it requires now collect the information in reverse, the main input's change fills related inputs. And the way I see it requires a lot of rows of code, which is not an option. Maybe somebody has done it before and knows a simple way.

in the DB I keep everything in one cell :

```
 COLOR { IMG => VALUE, PRICE => VALUE }, COLOR { IMG => VALUE..etc}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking for here.  Do you want advice about the bad DB schema? Do want want advice on how to build more complex HTML forms?  Do you want advice on how to wireframe the user experience? Why are "a lot of rows of code" not an option?  What is "a lot of rows of code" mean to you?

Comment: Any advice will do. I don't want to waste time. So I wanted to collect some information before doing it. But didn't find any suitable article. "DB I keep everything in one cell" - I am sorry, it was more as a vision. Another option is to keep all the variations in one table and product's main information in another. And for each variation save "product's id". Probably the form and the code manipulations depend on DP scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) kind of framework to build [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

OR use Ajax to call and fetch data for each action.

Loading all data and manipulate them in hidden fields, may makes things complicated.

I myself will either use MVC Framework (i.e. Angularjs) or jQuery ajax to load data according to each action.

Comment: At this point it is not so relevant what I use for coding, is it jQuery or AngularJS based. Mainly it's the question of the concept. Should I make tabs system where tabs name is the chosen color. Or maybe I should call a modal window and choose the color, price and everything else which is unique for a color beside pictures, and then just use pictures and tag them with color name. Every solution has pros and cons. But as I have never done it before. I might not know all the future hidden problems. So I wanted to get some tips from more informed.

Comment: By reading of your question, it is very difficult to know what you are asking. I answer according to my understanding to your question. Jquery and AngularJS has its own purpose. You need to choose what you wish to achieve as end result. You need to clarify you question little bit more. Reading question guideline http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yeah, I believe. I am sorry, using this service for the first time. Don't even know why I am here. Maybe was too desperate. I see too many solutions. And I can't just pick one. Can't understand even why. Sorry